# Adjust floats to satisfy the condition: abs(float) <= 0.5?

Tags: c++, algorithm, floating-point

I have got a vector of float of an arbitrary size. I would like to adjust the floats so that they satisfy the condition `abs(float) <= 0.5.` The fractional part should be preserved although it can differ from the original value, thus setting "x = 0.5" is incorrect. If the float is close to integer, discard it (the input float must not be an integer or close to one within an arbitrary precision).

This is what I wrote, but the code looks somewhat branchy. I wonder if there are ways to make it more elegant / efficient or there's something cruical I might have missed.

**Input:** float

**Output:** adjusted float x, so that fabs(x) <= 0.5

**Examples with integer part**

1. -5.3 -> -0.3 (take the fractional part, if abs(fractional) <= 0.5)
2. -5.8 -> 0.2 (add the closest integer, rounded upwards, relative to the absolute value).
3. 5.3 -> 0.3
4. 5.8 -> -0.2 (substract, but round down)
5. -5.5 -> -0.5 (sign is preserved here)
6. 5.5 -> 0.5 (sign is preserved here)

**Examples with only fractional part**

1. 0.3 -> 0.3
2. 0.8 -> -0.2 (substract 1)
3. -0.3 -> -0.3
4. -0.8 -> 0.2 (add the 1)

**Corner cases**

1. any integer -> 0
2. 0.5 -> 0.5
3. -0.5 -> -0.5

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

float scale(float x)
{
  const auto integerPart = std::abs(static_cast<std::int32_t>(x));
  const auto fractionalPart = std::fabs(x - static_cast<std::int32_t>(x));
  if (x < 0) {
    if (integerPart == 0) {
      if (fractionalPart > 0.5) {
       x += 1;
      }
    }
    else {
     x += integerPart + (fractionalPart > 0.5 ? 1 : 0);
    }
  }
  else {
    if (integerPart == 0) {
      if (fractionalPart > 0.5) {
        x -= 1;
      }
    } else {
      x -= integerPart + (fractionalPart > 0.5 ? 1 : 0);
    }
  }
  return x;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<float> floats(10000);

  static std::default_random_engine e;
  static std::uniform_real_distribution<float> distribution(-5, 5);

  std::generate(floats.begin(), 
                floats.end(), 
                [&]() { return distribution(e); });

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < floats.size(); ++i) {
    floats[i] = scale(floats[i]);
  }

  std::cout << std::boolalpha 
            << std::all_of(floats.cbegin(),
                           floats.cend(),
                           [&](const float x){ return std::fabs(x) <= 0.5; }) << "\n";

}
```

Sign preservation is relevant here, if fractional part exceeds 0.5, the sign of resulting value is inverted.

Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Could you give a few examples of how you want the numbers to be transformed?

Comment: @Beta Added the examples and elaboration. Please, check it, I woud add additional clarifications if required.

Comment: How about `x -= floorf(x); if (x > 0.5) x -= 1;`?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Wow, works great. The sign for x = -0.5 (or -5.5) is not preserved, though, it returns 0.5 instead of -0.5. I would accept it as answer.

Comment: better would be `const bool neg = std::signbit(x);`

Comment: Examples are not sufficient. You have to state your *rules.* You can't write computer programs from example data.

Comment: `static_cast<std::int32_t>(x)` is a problem when `x` outside `int32_t` range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `floor` function to reduce the amount of branches:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

float scale(float x) {
    bool neg = std::signbit(x);
    x -= std::floor(x + 0.5);
    if (!neg && x == -0.5) {
         return 0.5;
    } else {
         return x;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "-1.23 " << scale(-1.23) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-0.5 " << scale(-0.5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "0.123 " << scale(0.123) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "0.5 " << scale(0.5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1.23 " << scale(1.23) << std::endl;
}

-1.23 -0.23
-0.5 -0.5
0.123 0.123
0.5 0.5
1.23 0.23
```

Comment: Works flawlessly!

Comment: Note code uses `double` math with `x + 0.5`.  IMO, a better solution would not need wider math.  To only use `float` math, use `x + 0.5f`, but then `scale(nextafterf(0.5f, 0)));` fails - or many others when `x + 0.5f` is inexact.

Comment: Why not use `std::round(x)` instead of `std::floor(x+0.5)`?

Comment: Because I started with just `floor(x)` but then this need to have -0.5 and +0.5 results crept in. Note: std::round(-1.5) == -2, std::floor(-1.5 + 0.5) == -1. round goes towards the larger absolute value, floor towards the lower signed value.

Answer (score 3):

This is merely the `remainder` function except for the sign used when the result is exactly ±½, which can be adjusted by copying the sign from the input:

```
double ModifiedRemainder(double x)
{
    double y = std::remainder(x, 1);
    return std::fabs(y) == .5 ? std::copysign(y, x) : y;
}
```